# VB.net Bubble Graph BackImage

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a bubble graph in VS2010 - VB.Net. I am trying to change the background of each point in bubble graph.   But unable to. This is what I am trying :

```
    Dim s As New Series
    s.Name = "NewBubble"

    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble
    s.Points.AddXY(30, 22)
    s.Points.AddXY(30, 35)

    Dim Pathha As String = "C:\Users\Sample\Desktop\tenure-icon\Employee.PNG"
    s.Points(0).BackImage = (Pathha)
    s.Points(0).BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Tile   
    me.ChartSample.Series.Add(s)
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with below code : 
s.MarkerImage = Pathha